# Determine the closed form for $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sinh(xe^{-x})dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the closed form for

> $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sinh(xe^{-x})dx\tag1$$

Change to

$$I={1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{xe^{-x}}-e^{-xe^{-x}}dx)\tag2$$

Any hints? I can't go further.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you believe this admits some sort of closed form expression (in terms of elementary-ish functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By expanding the hyperbolic sine as a Taylor series we have:

> $$ I = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2n+1} e^{-(2n+1)x}\,dx = \color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2n+2}}} \tag{1}$$

with a series recalling [sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream). I won't bet on simple closed forms but in terms of integrals involving the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).